# How to turn double spacing off in longtable?

Tags: longtable, line-spacing, setspace

I have used the `setspace` package so it automatically turned off double spacing in tables, however the longtable are still double spaced. What should I do?

Comment: best not to use setspace but  otherwise just put `\singlespacing` before longtable

Comment: Thanks a lot, may I ask why best not to use setspace?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Is there a better way? How should double-spacing be configured?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Because every time you double space a document a typographer somewhere cries him (or her) self to sleep.

Comment: @cfr ^^^^^^^^^^

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Oh, right. I meant: is there a better way for all those times when you are required to double-space? Or, at least, all those times when I'm required to. Actually, I hate it when I get students' work which is not double-spaced. However, very few of them produce things which would not cause typographers to spin in their graves regardless.

Comment: My preferred solution would be for thesis candidates not to be such wimps and submit the documents without such typographic abuse. But I accept that not everyone wants to take that risk..

Comment: @DavidCarlisle All journals I've submitted to, all conferences and all anthologies require submissions to be double-spaced.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I am writing my thesis, and no I can't take that risk... :)

Comment: @cfr, I've taken a look just now, seems I cannot say thanks....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put `\singlespacing` before `longtable` and `\doublespacing` after if you want to return to that setting.